# Font Creator 6.0, how do I join points?

Tags: typography

I want this glyph to resemble a sort of elongated `^` shape (it was originally an accented A... `Á`).

I've deleted its vertical bar, but now it's completely filled in with black as you can see.

[image: glyph close up]

How can I just join those three points to form a `^`?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The program is trying to make a "cut" using the three interior nodes marked as red, but cannot complete the action because the cut is not inside the glyph.

Delete the 3 red nodes, make 3 new nodes along the bottom edge, and then drag them into position.  You may be able to do this by only deleting the top-most red node and making just one new node at bottom-center to drag back up.

Comment: Hi Brian! Welcome to GD.SE, and thanks for your answer!

Comment: An absolute pleasure!  And I hope it helps out; I'm only speaking from crude experience with FontLab.  :)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell, but it looks like you have three contours left. The accent and two that once represented the A. You need to have only two.

I think it is easiest if you start all over and make sure you don't remove points you wish to keep. The manual has a lot of information about how to manipulate points.
See the online manual:
http://www.high-logic.com/fontcreator/manual7/simpleglyphsintroduction.html

Alternatively you can add points to the outer contour of the A, and remove the inner contour.